# If Squeak is not a script language, then where is the tree data structure?

Tags: data-structures, smalltalk, squeak

Because Squeak is a open source environment, we can see the implementation of data structures like `OrderedCollection>>addFirst`:

```
addFirst: newObject 
"Add newObject to the beginning of the receiver. Answer newObject."

firstIndex = 1 ifTrue: [self makeRoomAtFirst].
firstIndex := firstIndex - 1.
array at: firstIndex put: newObject.
^ newObject
```

and `OrderedCollection>>removeFirst`:

```
removeFirst: n
"Remove first n object into an array"

| list |
list := Array new: n.
1 to: n do: [:i |
    list at: i put: self removeFirst].
^ list
```

Then I can manipulate a stack data structure, correct?

I am informed that Smalltalk has no pointer structure; though languages like Java also have no pointer structure, Not as a script language, it should implement some fundamental data structure like tree, diagram (referred by [Scripting: Higher Level Programming
for the 21st Century](http://home.pacbell.net/ouster/scripting.html)), then rise the further question :

How does Smalltalk implement a tree data structure?

Comment: I've attempted to improve the English of your question. If I've changed what you meant to say, please correct me.

Comment: I don't see why you make the relation between scripting language and tree data structure. Btw "scripting language" is a non-expression IMHO.

Comment: Scripting languages like perl， Tcl represend some kinds of glue, like pipe in unix, but they are not suitable for use in algorithms area, however, small talk as an OO language, it should implement algoritms, data structure etc. That's the opionion, frind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smalltalk has pointers everywhere, just like Java does. You can't do C-like things like increment pointers, but `myVar := OrderedCollection new` means that `myVar` is a pointer pointing to an empty `OrderedCollection`.

Yes, you can simulate a stack using OrderedCollection by using `addFirst:` to push elements and `removeFirst:` and `removeFirst` to pop elements. (Similarly, you can simulate a queue by pushing elements with `addFirst:` and removing them with `removeLast`.

You can implement trees in Smalltalk the same way you do in any language. For instance, I wrote a [very basic tree implementation](http://www.squeaksource.com/Zippers.html) for playing around with [zippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29). Look at class `ZTree`, which implements a very general tree structure - a node may have any number of children.

Comment: "pointer arithmetic" is the term for what Smalltalk and Java are "missing".

Comment: "Missing" here means "makes no sense in this language" rather than "gosh we forgot".

Comment: I have viewd your ZTree code, it sounds good:) thanks your answer, and I gonner to know small talk is a typeless language, modern computer language except script language have types, May be typeless is one of the reason why smalltalk cannot be as popular as java,c++, etc.

Comment: It's not a typeless language. _Variables_ have no type, but _values_ are strongly typed (in the sense that you may not subvert the type system). See http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?TypelessVsDynamic for instance.